# Built-in Ruby methods

Tags: ruby, methods

If there is a defined built in ruby method, is it always preferable to use the built-in method?

If I have code such as:

```
if i == 0
```

What is the advantage to instead using the built-in ruby method?

```
if i.zero?
```

Comment: Readability maybe?

Comment: are you asking about `i.zero?` vs `i == 0` or about generic, built-in methods? ps. `==` is also the method.

Comment: For that particular example, universal use of `zero?` would eliminate thousands of inadvertent `i = 0`'s daily.

Comment: Has any answer been helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written simple test:

```
require 'benchmark'

l = 0

funcs =
[ proc { l == 0 },
  proc { l.zero? },
]

def ctime func
   time = 0
   1000.times { time += Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { func.call } }.to_a[5].to_f }
   rtime = time /= 1000000
end

funcs.each {| func | p ctime( func ) }

# 4.385690689086914e-07
# 4.829726219177246e-07
```

As you can see `:zero?` method takes a few additional time (about 10%) against the `:==` method, so it is slower than `:==`. Second, since `:zero?` method is included only in `Numeric` class and its descendants, you can use it only on numbers.

Answer (score 5):

`i.zero?` works only if `i` is [`Numeric`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html) object.

```
i = nil
i == 0
# => false
i.zero?
# NoMethodError: undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass
#        from (irb):5
#        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The implications?  `zero?` might be preferred when `i` is intended to be Numeric, so would raise an exception if not? `==` might be preferred if we wanted to know if an object is either not Numeric or Numeric and not zero?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, those kinds of methods are for doing something like:

```
array.delete_if &:zero?
```

It may be preferable to use `== 0` in if statements and such for consistency, but this is now more of a matter of opinion.

If you think `zero?` is more readable, use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a New Year's resolution to make greater use of Ruby methods that end with a question mark.  I think doing do so will make my code more expressive and also cut down on errors.  The most obvious example of the latter is using `eql?` instead of `==` (for comparing objects of class `Object`, not to be confused with `equal?`).  But how often do you see `x.eql? 7` instead of `x == 7`?  Probably less often than you see `x = 7`, when `x == 7` was intended.

Some others that seem to get less respect than they deserve include (the afore-mentioned) `zero?`, `nonzero?`, `integer?`, `empty?`, `any?`, `all?`, `nil?`, `none?`, `one?`, `start_with?` and `end_with?`.